# TableView Lag in Swift (constraints error in output)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, constraints

I have a big problem in scrolling with my TableView. The output of the console is:

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-04-05 10:55:48.970850+0200 Elly App[4518:132337] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
**(
**"**<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002d67160 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x144d1d540.minY == 57.6667   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x144d142d0 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002d671b0 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x144d1d540.height == 24.3333   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d66b20 V:|-(88)-[UILabel:0x144d1d260]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x144d142d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d66a80 V:[UIImageView:0x144d1d540]-(0)-[UILabel:0x144d1d260]   (active)>"
)**

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d66a80 V:[UIImageView:0x144d1d540]-(0)-[UILabel:0x144d1d260]   (active)>

How can I resolve it? Thank You a Lot.

Ps: this is my first question on stackoverflow...

Comment: You most probably made a mistake in defining your layout. But without more context (e.g. the constraint defining code) it is hard to tell.

Comment: I set constraints only manually with constraints menu at the right of xcode. I don't have any code about constraint